# How to add the state names to the Australia map?

Tags: r

I have written the following code:

```
library(ozmaps)
oz(states = TRUE, coast = TRUE,
   ylim = NULL, add = FALSE, ar = 1, eps = 0.25)
```

That generates:
[image]

I wonder how to add the names of the states on the map? If the whole process can be done by "map" package, it is fine as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with package `ozmaps`. I could not find data for the state names and latitude and longitude values for state centroids within the package.

A quick internet search produced some representative state data from https://www.distancelatlong.com/distancecalculator/country/australia/

You can adjust this data or find a better source, so this should be a start.

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(ozmaps)

ggplot(ozmap_states)+
  geom_sf()+
  geom_text(data = oz_states, aes(long, lat, label = state))+
  theme_void()
```

#### data

```
oz_states <- tribble(
~state, ~lat, ~long,
"Australian Capital Territory", -35.3546004,    149.2113468,
"New South Wales",  -33.42004148,   151.3000048,
"Northern Territory", -13.81617348, 131.816698,
"Queensland",   -26.67998777,   153.0500272,
"South Australia",  -34.28293455,   140.6000378,
"Tasmania", -40.83292234,   145.1166613,
"Victoria", -37.73119953,   142.0234135,
"Western Australia",    -33.58287392,   120.0333345
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>